# Como adicionar um tempo para passar o slider?

Tags: jquery, html, slider

Olá, eu sou novato aqui e também em jquery. E eu queria saber como faço para adicionar um tempo para que passe de um slide pro outro, eis o codigo:

```html
   

    <div id="slide" align="center">
<ul>
<li id="frame"><div></div><div class="text"><a href="#"><h1>Título</h1></a><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ornare neque ante. Duis eget nisl eget lacus gravida laoreet vel id ipsum. Pellentesque consectetur pellentesque nisi at tincidunt. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In lorem neque, lacinia ut leo eget, imperdiet iaculis risus. Cras posuere fringilla arcu, ac auctor tortor varius ut.</p></div></li>

<li id="frame2"><div></div><div class="text2"><a href="#"><h1>Título</h1></a><p>Sed quis nibh ultrices dolor lobortis facilisis sed mattis enim. Proin a arcu elementum, rhoncus enim in, lacinia est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce ut mollis ipsum. Nunc eleifend libero vitae neque vulputate scelerisque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut volutpat quis nibh nec elementum.</p></div></li>

<li id="frame3"><div></div><div class="text3"><a href="#"><h1>Título</h1></a><p>Etiam imperdiet felis in cursus tempus. Sed finibus accumsan tellus et porta. Vivamus a pretium neque. Nam eu arcu ac massa hendrerit pharetra vitae ut libero. Nulla posuere vulputate aliquam. Nunc non elit lacus. Mauris vulputate tellus ac ullamcorper cursus. Aliquam ullamcorper velit tempus, tristique ligula id, pellentesque justo. Sed quis vehicula ex, et tristique dui. In eleifend vel dui eget gravida. Aenean vitae egestas risus. Nam vel quam auctor, ultricies tortor eget, sodales purus.</p></div></li>
</ul>

<ul>
<a href="#"><button id="button1"></button></a>
<a href="#"><button id="button2"></button></a>
<a href="#"><button id="button3"></button></a>
</ul>
</div>
```

E aqui está o jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#frame2").hide();
        $("#frame3").hide();



        $( "#button1" ).click(function slide1() {
        $( "#frame" ).show("drop");
        $("#frame2").hide();
        $("#frame3").hide();
            });

        $( "#button2" ).click(function slide2() {
        $( "#frame2" ).show("drop");
        $("#frame").hide();
        $("#frame3").hide();
            });

        $( "#button3" ).click(function slide3() {
        $( "#frame3" ).show("drop");
        $("#frame2").hide();
        $("#frame").hide();
            });
```

Eu queria saber como q eu consigo passar do slide1 pro slide2 e dai pro slide3 e fazer novamente com um tempo definido. Obrigado desde já.

Desculpem ai se eu coloquei algo errado -.-'

Comment: Queres que os slides vão mudando sem ter de carregar nos botões? ou queres manter também os botões?

Answer (score 1):

No código que você postou faltava fechar um bloco. Com o fechamento do bloco, e mudando o `show('drop')` para `fadeIn ()` você pode controlar o tempo que demorará para aparecer a div com `slow`, `fast`, ou em milisegundos.

Criei um fiddle pra demonstrar (como sugeriu o @Sergio numa pergunta minha :-)), e to postando abaixo o exemplo verificável. No exemplo coloquei 5000 milisegundos, mas vc pode mudar como quiser:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/m1dd93t4/1/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#frame2").hide();
        $("#frame3").hide();
        });

        $( "#button1" ).click(function slide1() {
        $( "#frame" ).fadeIn(5000);
        $("#frame2").hide();
        $("#frame3").hide();
            });

        $( "#button2" ).click(function slide2() {
        $( "#frame2" ).fadeIn (5000);
        $("#frame").hide();
        $("#frame3").hide();
            });

        $( "#button3" ).click(function slide3() {
        $( "#frame3" ).fadeIn(5000);
        $("#frame2").hide();
        $("#frame").hide();
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slide" align="center">
<ul>
<li id="frame"><div></div><div class="text"><a href="#"><h1>Título 1</h1></a><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ornare neque ante. Duis eget nisl eget lacus gravida laoreet vel id ipsum. Pellentesque consectetur pellentesque nisi at tincidunt. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In lorem neque, lacinia ut leo eget, imperdiet iaculis risus. Cras posuere fringilla arcu, ac auctor tortor varius ut.</p></div></li>

<li id="frame2"><div></div><div class="text2"><a href="#"><h1>Título 2</h1></a><p>Sed quis nibh ultrices dolor lobortis facilisis sed mattis enim. Proin a arcu elementum, rhoncus enim in, lacinia est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce ut mollis ipsum. Nunc eleifend libero vitae neque vulputate scelerisque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut volutpat quis nibh nec elementum.</p></div></li>

<li id="frame3"><div></div><div class="text3"><a href="#"><h1>Título 3 </h1></a><p>Etiam imperdiet felis in cursus tempus. Sed finibus accumsan tellus et porta. Vivamus a pretium neque. Nam eu arcu ac massa hendrerit pharetra vitae ut libero. Nulla posuere vulputate aliquam. Nunc non elit lacus. Mauris vulputate tellus ac ullamcorper cursus. Aliquam ullamcorper velit tempus, tristique ligula id, pellentesque justo. Sed quis vehicula ex, et tristique dui. In eleifend vel dui eget gravida. Aenean vitae egestas risus. Nam vel quam auctor, ultricies tortor eget, sodales purus.</p></div></li>
</ul>

<ul>
<a href="#"><button id="button1">título 1</button></a>
<a href="#"><button id="button2">título 2</button></a>
<a href="#"><button id="button3">título 3</button></a>
</ul>
</div>
```

Agora se o que você quer é ir passando as `divs` sem ter clicar no botão, então acho que vc quer algo [tipo isso](http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/CcWgv/).